# Auto-populate a TextBox when selecting value in a ComboBox

Tags: vba, vlookup

I have two fields on my UserForm; one is a ComboBox and another is a TextBox.

Based on the ComboBox value, I have populated the value of the TextBox.

But I have to click on the TextBox field to get automatic value.

I want the TextBox to be updated as soon as I select a value in the ComboBox, without the need to click on the TextBox.

My code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate()
    With Me
        .TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1, Sheet2.Range("C:D"), 2, False)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the `ComboBox`'s `Change` event, rather than its `AfterUpdate` event.  I think that will do what you want to do.

Comment: it certainly will!

Comment: Thanks a lot Gene.This change event does exactly what i want.But it affects the next functionality like....                                                               .TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1, Sheet2.Range("C:D"), 2, False)    . This line helps in looking up the value corresponding to combobox1.

Comment: Thank you YowE3K...Could you please help .